# Inverse Telecine (IVTC) anime DVDs

Tags: ffmpeg, hevc

### Issue

I have a bunch of anime I've ripped from DVDs and even BDs that are 480i.

I want to upscale these videos with Topaz Video AI for higher quality on a big screen, but also because subtitles are a blurry mess at 480px height unless the player I use keeps the resolution at 1080p or 4K.

In this case, the upscale is introducing interlacing artifacts that aren't in the original file.

### Anime Framerate

Anime is `23.976`fps yet the files on the discs are `29.970`fps at what is essentially `60i`.

The first frame is duplicated twice and the second 3 times, then twice for the 3rd frame, and 3 times for the 4th. This is 2:3 pulldown.

Devices can do inverse telecine to get back the original 23.976fps video in realtime, but to upscale, I need to convert it to `23.976`fps first on disk, then send that file to the upscaler.

### `ffmpeg`

I'm trying to use ffmpeg to convert these files, but my command seems to be broken. Can you help me figure out how to alter this command to achieve my intended results at minimal to no quality loss?

This is the command I settled on so far:

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mkv" -c copy -map 0 -map_metadata 0 -vf "pullup" -c:v hevc_nvenc -profile:v main10 -level:v 4.1 -crf 18 -preset slow -fps_mode cfr -tag:v hvc1 -r 24000/1001 "output.mkv"
```

I added `-level:v 4.1` because the original file is L4.1. For some reason, it gets converted to L3 without this change. I'd rather just say "use whatever it was originally", but I haven't figured out how.

I'm also converting to HEVC **not** because I care about compression, but because I think it produces a higher-quality encode. Especially if I'm going lossy to lossy, I want to lose as little detail as possible, so I figured AVC to HEVC should be safe. *This assumption could be incorrect.*

### File still shows Interlaced

So long as I've done everything correct up to this point, my remaining issue is the file showing "Interlaced" when it should be, and visually looks, progressive.

Original file specs:

[image: Original file specs]

Resulting file showing Interlaced:

[image: Resulting file showing Interlaced]

### Keyframes are wrong

For some reason, after converting, the keyframes are wrong. I might not be understanding this term correctly, but when I seek through the file, it goes in 10- and 11-second intervals. The original file lets me seek in 1-second intervals.